# How to i know android app supports 64bit?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, 64-bit, google-console-developer

I have changed the gradle to something like this,

[image]
which is in accordance with the documentation from Google Dev.

then how do I know if my application supports 64 bits?

I tried with Build -> Analyze APK, but I did not find the lib folder or file with the format .so. 
[image]
how to solved this?

Comment: documentation on the 64 bit support, from Google itself: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: According to doc if lib folder is not contain in generated apk then your application support both 32 and 64 bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64 bit change only affects apps that use "native code", ie code that compiles for the processor on the device, as opposed to being written in Java or Kotlin.

This will only be true for you if:

- You have written such native code (probably in C or C++) using the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)
- You use a third party library that has native code

If the former, then you should know how to target more processors ([See this page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html)).
If the latter then you will need to talk to the developer of the third party library.

But if your app has no .so files, and it is entirely written in Java or Kotlin, you don't need to do anything, it supports 64 bit.